# Wordpress - How to get the next new post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to get the next new post ID in a product page.

So I know how to get last post id in DB, but I need to know second new post ID.

```
function GetLastPostId()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $row = $result[0];
    $id = $row->ID;

    return $id;
}
```

The problem is, for example, know the last post id is 1510, but then I create product - post id becaume 1513 not 1511 (added 3 not 1). Then I Delete some pages/products it adds 2 not 3 or sometimes 1

So is it possible to get next post id some how?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a post id of the product not added yet?

Comment: Yes, in a new product page. I need to get his ID (product not created yet)

Comment: Just for FYI, the reason it add 3 not 1 to postId because wordpress use same table to create other record type as well when you post a new post. Those other record could be 1511 and 1511.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;

$result  = $wpdb->get_results( "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts'", ARRAY_A );

echo( $result[0]['Auto_increment']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get second largest post id change your query to limit 1,1

$query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,1";

Comment: Oh you want to get id still not created,i think you need to get second largest id. Try this    $next_post = get_next_post();

$post_id = $next_post->id;

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function SecondLastPostId()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,1";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $row = $result[0];
    $id = $row->ID;

    return $id;
}
```

Note at `WHERE post_type = 'post'` and `LIMIT 1,1` , you may change it to `post_type = 'product'` based on your post type

Comment: Your code returns the id of the product already added in databases. From the comment we see that Mantas need an id of the product that is not in db yet.

Comment: @IvnH you are right, but i believe wordpress automatically save into the db already even if the post is not created yet ( while creating the post ) , just the `post_type` is something else. Need to look into what post_type wordpress use.

Comment: Yes, not working, I change to post_type to a product, but same, showing not the next id.

Comment: @Mantas'MG'G. I'll suggest some ways to debug. 1. When it doesn't work what ID it shows? 2. Open phpMyAdmin and look into the tables what records are there and what do you expect. It will start to make more sense :)

Comment: not a good practice to use direct sql queries in WordPress.